# Tk window returns AttributeError: __len__

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Here I'm starting to create a TK window with a text field but when ever I run this I get the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "School.py", line 31, in begin
    emulatorI=emulator()
  File "School.py", line 20, in __init__
    code.pack(self.root)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1868, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1105, in _options
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 114, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1826, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: __len__
```

from within the module. What am I doing wrong? I'm realitively new to classes so I may have done something wrong in the class setup.

I'm running python 2.7 on OS 10.9

```
class emulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.geometry("500x500")

        self.root.title("Python")

        code=Text(self.root)
        code.pack(self.root)

        self.root.mainloop()

emulatorI=emulator()
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line

```
code.pack(self.root)
```

The `pack` function normally takes no arguments except keyword arguments, and so should just be called as

```
code.pack()
```

The reason for the very odd error is that `pack` *can* take a positional argument, which is expected to be a dictionary of options. When trying to treat the `Tk` instance as a dictionary, it failed due to the lack of a `__len__` method.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of code.pack(self.root)?

The arguments for pack are placement directions, such as side, padding, fill, anchor, etc
(see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm ).